# oncomplete transition in Semantic Ui

Tags: javascript, html, transition, semantic-ui

Well, I use semantic UI in my project, And now I get stuck and the problem is -- I want to hide a element `#header_1` with transition and after the transition is complete I use behavior `onComplete` to show another element `#hidden`

Here's my Html Code

```
<div id="header_1">
    <a href="#" class="ui animated inverted large button uk-margin-small-bottom" id="play">
</div>
<div id="hidden">
    Booommm!!!!
</div>
```

And Here's my javascript code

```
$('#play').click(function(){
    $('#header_1').transition({
        animation : 'fade',
        duration : '500ms',
        onComplete : function(){
            $('#hidden').transition({'show'});
    }
});
```

});

Sorry for bad english, and please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Official Documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/transition.html#/definition) you should not use curly braces in the transition notation, i.e. your code should look like this:

```
...
onComplete : function(){
    $('#hidden').transition('show');
}
...
```

Comment: but' get another problem now, how can i hide #hidden when the first transition didn't start?

Comment: You should solve this through CSS. Just add class='hidden' to the #hidden div and you are all set.

Comment: Okey.. this is a great site :D